# Dropdown Onchange() value with 3 dropdown category related each others

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onchange

I have 3 dropdown category which are **Length, width, Area.**

For example :-

if I choose the length unit to **feet** from length dropdown category, the second and third dropdown category which is width and area will automatically change to **feet for width** and **sqft for area**. Furthermore, When I change the second dropdown category which is width to **meter**, the **length unit category dropdownlist** and **area unit category dropdownlist** will automatically change to **meter for length** and **m2 for area**.

Then, it will display unit measure system for each category in input box below.
if value is ***feet***, it becomes ***imperial***. if value is ***meter***, then it becomes ***metric***.

How to achieve this scenario in JQuery/Javascript code? Thanks in advance.

```html
<label>Length </label>
  <select id="length" name="length">
    <option value="" selected="selected" onchange="length()">--Unit--</option>
    <option value="feet">feet</option>
    <option value="meter">meter</option>
  </select>
  
 
 <label>Width </label>
  <select id="width" name="width">
    <option value="" selected="selected" onchange="width()">--Unit--</option>
        <option value="feet">feet</option>
        <option value="meter">meter</option>
  </select>
  
  
  <label>Area </label>
  <select id="area" name="area">
    <option value="" selected="selected" onchange="area()">--Unit--</option>
        <option value="feet">sqft.</option>
        <option value="meter">m2</option>
  </select>
  
  <div id="m">
    <input type="text" id="measure"/>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting the elements using js `document.querySelector` and then attaching `Event Listener` ( in this case we use will `change` event ).... So when there is change in the select field ( whose changes is desired ) we can do some function !

**HTML**

```
   <label for="length">Length </label>
   <select id="length" name="length">
        <option value="" selected="selected" >--Unit--</option>
        <option value="feet">feet</option>
        <option value="meter">meter</option>
      </select>
      
     
     <label for="width">Width </label>
      <select id="width" name="width">
        <option value="" selected="selected">--Unit--</option>
            <option value="feet">feet</option>
            <option value="meter">meter</option>
      </select>
      
      
      <label for="area">Area </label>
      <select id="area" name="area">
        <option value="" selected="selecte">--Unit--</option>
            <option value="feet">sqft.</option>
            <option value="meter">m2</option>
      </select>
      
      <div id="m">
        <input type="text" id="measure"/>
      </div>
```

**JS**

```
    const length_field = document.querySelector('#length');
    
    const width_field = document.querySelector('#width');
    
    const area_field = document.querySelector('#area');
    
    length_field.addEventListener('change' , function (e){
      // using condition 
       if(this.value === "feet"){
          area_field.value = "feet";
          width_field.value = "feet";
       }else if(this.value === "meter"){
          area_field.value = "meter";
          width_field.value = "meter";
       }else{
         // do nothing by default 
       }
    })
```

Comment: Hi @sanmeet it works properly. Thank you for your help